# how to ensure no duplicates records in mongodb while inserting without using indexing?

Tags: mongodb

I fetch data daily from a source which gives same record twice or thrice.
I want to ensure unique record in my database without using the indexing.

Comment: hi, welcome, Please edit your question and provide more information - There is not enough information. Also, write your query and read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the records are in a canonical format and are not too large you could take a hash of each record and store the hashes as the _id key of the document during insertion (this is automatically indexed and you can't turn off the index).

In Python (you need the pymongo driver installed `pip install pymongo`).

```py
>>> import json
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db=client['test']
>>> collection=db['test']
>>> a={"a":"b"}
>>> s = json.dumps(a)
>>> hash(s)
7926683998783294113
>>> collection.insert_one({"_id" : hash(s), "data" : a})
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x104ff7bc8>
>>> collection.insert_one({"_id" : hash(s), "data" : a})
...
    raise DuplicateKeyError(error.get("errmsg"), 11000, error)
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: _id_ dup key: { : 7926683998783294113 }
>>>
```

So to detect your duplicate records just catch `DuplicateKeyError`. This approach
presumes that the `dumps` output is identical for identical records.